# Iterate through a hash and an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, hash

I have an array and a hash:

```
@arraycodons = "AATG", "AAAA", "TTGC"... etc.
%hashdictionary = ("AATG" => "A", "AAAA" => "B"... etc.)
```

I need to translate each element of the array for the corresponding value in hashdictionary. However, I obtain a wrong translation.....

To see the problem, I have printed $codon (each element of the array), but each codon is repeated several times..... and It shouldn't.

```
sub translation() {
    foreach $codon (@arraycodons) {
        foreach $k (keys %hashdictionary) {
            if ($codon == $k) {
                $v = $hashdictionary{$k};
                print $codon;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I've explained my problem well enough, but I can't go on with my code if this doesn't work...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `eq` for string comparison, not `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @words = ("car", "house", "world"); 
my %dictionary = ("car" => "el coche", "house" => "la casa", "world" => "el mundo"); 
my @keys = keys %dictionary; 


foreach(@words) {
my $word = $_; 
foreach(@keys) {
    if($_ eq $word) { # eq, not ==
        my $translation = $dictionary{$_}; 
        print "The Spanish translation of $word is $translation\n"; 
    }

}
}
```

Comment: The inner loop and if are equivalent to `my $translation = $dictionary{$word}`, see @PP.'s answer.

Comment: Yes, no need to iterate. Just wanted to stick roughly to the author's code ... I myself would probably have written something similiar to Ashalynd's answer, it is very 'perlish'.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be looping through the keys of your hash (also known as a "dictionary") to find your desired key. This defeats the purpose of a hash (also known as a "dictionary") - the primary advantage of which is ultra fast lookups of a key.

Try, instead of

```
foreach $codon (@arraycodons) {
    foreach $k (keys %hashdictionary) {
        if ($codon == $k) {
            $v = $hashdictionary{$k};
            print $codon;
        }
    }
}
```

this:

```
foreach $codon (@arraycodons) {
    my $value = $hashdictionary{$codon};
    print( "$codon => $value\n" );
}
```

or:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %hashdictionary ) {
    my $value = $hashdictionary{$key};
    print( "$key => $value\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my @mappedcodons = map {$hashdictionary{$_}} 
                  grep (defined $hashdictionary{$_},@arraycodons);
```

or

```
my @mappedcodons = grep ($_ ne "", map{$hashdictionary{$_} || ""} @arraycodons);
```

Comment: What about words which aren't mapped? Consider `$hashdictionary{$_} // $_`

Comment: added filtering (the original code didn't print unmatched entries)